# How to make a heatmap and the matrix for it?

Tags: matrix, heatmap

I'm lost as to how we make a heatmap on rstudio. I have tried to make the matrix with my data but I seem to fail to comprehend how to make it and only NA appears in it.

I have tried to make a matrix with set.seed, but Like said before I don't understand how it works. I also know you may use your data frame to do a heatmap but I also don't know how to do it.

Sorry if its not well explain, I am quite new to rstudio.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.